# should I use a js function other than console.log(message)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use console.log(message) to write out some information to the browser console.  However, I came across this url which seems to recommend against it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Are you currently choosing to use console.log(message) as part of your js code?  If not then have you identified an alternative?

Comment: While it isn't standard, it is available just about everywhere. As it is, you should only be logging to the console when you're debugging code. Remove any log statements before pushing to production. If you're writing Javascript for modern browsers, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mike C above-- `console` is generally available in most browsers, but you should probably remove `console` logs before a site gets pushed to production.

Additionally, some older browser might *not* have the `console`, and if you *did* accidentally leave in a console log, it would fire an error when it attempted to interact with with something that wasn't defined.  As an extra failsafe, you can declare `console` and `console.log` in the global namespace if they are not detected, just in case:

```
if (!console) {
    console = {
        log: function () { //noop }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**should I use a js function other than console.log(message)?**

simple answer is yes, But also the console.log(message) is usaually used for testing purposes and for other relevant intentions like letting other developers interract with your js source code in some sort.

**However.**

You should not use it to log very important messages as this could be a hole your application presumably.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

While the `console` object is not defined in the official Javascript standard, it is specified in:

- [Google Chrome](https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#consolelogobject--object-)
- [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)
- [Internet Explorer 9+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/console/)
- [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html)
- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html)
- [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/hello.js) (since it uses V8 like Chrome and Node.js)

and more, I'm sure. As long as you're debugging in any of the environments which supports it, you're fine. You should be removing your logging statements before pushing to production anyway so as long as it works for debugging, it's nothing to worry about.